# como especificar content-type en fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

Tengo un **endpoint** el cual se probo con **postman* y da la respuesta esperada, pero a la hora de utilizar con `javaScript` 2 errores.

1. *falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'* el cual de momento ignoro con `mode: 'no-cors'`
2. Me regresa el siguiente mensaje

> El mensaje entrante tiene un formato de mensaje inesperado 'Raw'. Los formatos de mensaje esperados para la operación son 'Xml', 'Json'. Esto se puede deber a que no se ha configurado un WebContentTypeMapper en el enlace. Para obtener más información, consulte la documentación de WebContentTypeMapper

entiendo que el mensaje hace referencia a que la información se le envía en formato text, pero la configuración de mi `fetch` es la siguiente

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    accept: '/',
  },
  mode: 'no-cors',
  body: data,
})
```

el `body` lo he enviado de dos formas

```
body: JSON.stringify(data)
```

o

```
body: data
```

Hasta el momento no se como darle solución y algo que noto en el navegador es que el `content-type` aparece en text y en **postman** esta en `json`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por lo que muestra el navegador el `content-type` siempre va en text/plain

Answer (score 1):

Según [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

> Tenga en cuenta que  mode: "no-cors" solo permite un conjunto limitado de encabezados en la solicitud:
>
> 1. Accept
> 2. Accept-Language
> 3. Content-Language
> 4. Content-Type con valor de **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**, **multipart/form-data**, o **text/plain**

Es decir, usando no-cors no se admite application/json, por lo que automáticamente se pasa a text/plain (lo que entiende como Raw) mientras que espera json o xml.

Comment: Ok, entonces intentare que configuren el endpoint con las cors, la duda también es por que si funciona con **Postman** pero no en javaScript, que hace **Postman** unico que acepta sin problemas la petición?

Comment: Con postman puedes escribir muchas peticiones que no son realmente válidas o equivalentes en web/js. Quizás esté enviando un application/json sin cors sin transformar a raw, y el endpoint lo esté aceptando. Si quieres comparar mejor, tendrás que ver toda la petición HTTP construida. Lo más fácil, si en postman no tienes un resumen es que la imprimas en el servidor si tienes acceso a él o te hagas un pequeño endpoint con node o lo que quieras solo con este fin. Considera aceptar esta respuesta si ha resuelto tu duda.